# Sharepoint Services 3 Search Broken

Tags: sharepoint

I am getting the following error for WSS3

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   Windows SharePoint Services 3 Search
Event Category: Gatherer
Event ID:   2424
User:       N/A
Description:
The update cannot be started because the content sources cannot be
accessed. Fix the errors and try the update again.

Context: Application 'Search', Catalog 'index file on the search
server Search'

Search used to work in the past - I've made sure that it is not using any built in accounts. I've tried creating new accounts as well and reverting to using an older account.

Still no luck.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A month or two ago we ran into a similar problem after installing .NET 3.5 SP1 on our SharePoint 2007 server. Our problem was caused by NTLM loopback authentication.  We fixed the problem using Method 2 as described in this KB article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Answer (score 1):

A couple of questions:

-When did you start to get this message?

-Did anything change before you started to get this message?

I have seen this error when the WSS Search service account is set to use the Network Service account (which you say it is not, but check out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927012), and have also seen it if the Alternate Access Mappings were not setup correctly (see more here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288173.aspx)

-Sean

Comment: Hi,
Yes turns out the auth was set to kerberos. Extending the application via MSS administration to use NTLM got it working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this for a while because we were using basic authentication. For the crawler to work, it has to be able to use integrated authentication to get to the site. Also, I found that to get it to work, I had to set up the default web application to use integrated authentication and then use an extended web application for other authentication schemes.